# array_unshift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Tags: php-7.4

I want to add data to my array using array_unshift() but it
shows " array_unshift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given "

here is my code:

```
public function index($child = null)
{
    $crumbs = [];

    function getParents($id){
        $parent = Instrument::where('id', $id)->first(['id', 'title', 'parent']);

        if($parent->parent != null){
            array_unshift($crumbs, $parent);
            getParents($parent->parent);
        }
    }

    if($child != null){ 
        getParents($child);
    }
    
    //return code here
}
```

do you have any solution?

BTW, I am using Laravel 8, PHP 7.4.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable `$crumbs` isn't visible in `getParents` function.

So you should pass it as an argument or make it a global variable or make a property for an object.

```
public function index($child = null)
{
    $crumbs = [];

    function getParents($id, &$crumbs){
        $parent = Instrument::where('id', $id)->first(['id', 'title', 'parent']);

        if($parent->parent != null){
            array_unshift($crumbs, $parent);
            getParents($parent->parent);
        }
    }

    if($child != null){
        getParents($child, $crumbs);
    }

    //return code here
}
```

For example like this.

Comment: thanks for that i forgot php can't read variable outside function